# Setting Gain, Expo and Sensitivity with DJI-SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

Is there a way to get/set Gain, Expo and Sensitivity through the DJI-SDK, like you can do in the DJI-GO App, through the Settings/Aircraft/Advanced window?

Comment: Seems like it is not possible to get/set Gain, Expo, and Sensitivity through DJI-SDK. Got below response from the team DJI

"Unfortunately, MSDK does not provide those API interface to adjust the EXT, GAIN and SENSITIVITY. Although GO4 support, it is not develped by using MSDK, DJI Pilot is an official app that developed by MSDK. We cannot find those seetings on DJI Pilot App and we have confirmed with the devs team that we do not provide such inferface in MSDK. Sorry!"

I hope this answer will help other developers searching for the solution to get/set parameters using DJI-SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I see - I did give the wrong answer.  The Gain, Expo and Sensitivity features are not exposed in DJI's SDKs but you can submit a feature request for these to dev@dji.com.  If you do, please describe what your use case for these APIs would be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - look under class **Camera** in DJI's APIs at developer.dji.com

Comment: This is not related to the Camera at all. It's the setting for flight control - stick sensitivity and aircraft response.